# System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error or missing database no such table: HangFire.JobQueue

Tags: sqlite, hangfire

I am using SQLite Database with Hangfire and I am facing two issues

1. When I click on Enqueued Tab `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException`: SQL logic error or missing database no such table: `HangFire.JobQueue` appears, Error only produced when there are
   some jobs in Queue. I am using this [Hangfire.SQLite](https://github.com/wanlitao/HangfireExtension) extension
   given on Hangfire website
2. 2nd issue is with multiple workers there occurs concurrency problem
   in the count of Succeeded Jobs.

   ```
    var options = new SQLiteStorageOptions();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSQLiteStorage("SQLiteHangfire", options);
    var option = new BackgroundJobServerOptions { WorkerCount = Environment.ProcessorCount * 10 };
    app.UseHangfireServer(option);
   ```

Any help regarding these issues.